# Radio button turned into stars not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

[THis is what i did with jquery. Does it even submit my rating?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwz25.png)[image: I have mada ratimg column as well but when submitted i dont see rating in params.]

The above code is not submitting the rating. Does it even work that way? If not, how can I do it?

Please kindly help me with the solution.

Comment: Added pic of code (step-by-step improvement)

Comment: By doing that does it sends the value when i click the stars ? i did but it was not happening.